# How to display plain text in outlook new mail popup for multipart message

Tags: html, outlook, swiftmailer, plaintext

I am using the Swiftmailer class in combination with Zend Framework to send mail from my website. The message is a mix of html and plain text, and I have implemented it like this:

```
// Or set it after like this
$message->setBody('My <em>amazing</em> body', 'text/html');

// Add alternative parts with addPart()
$message->addPart('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');
```

Like this excerpt from the documentation.
The problem is, the blue new mail notification popup of outlook displays the first two lines of the html message after the  section. So, for instance,  tags are displayed. How can I format my message using the Swiftmailer class so that outlook uses the plain text representation for the preview?
I know it is possible, because sending html mail from outlook itself doesn't result in tags in the preview popup.
Thanks in advance for any hint!